# Is the expression $S=K \log(\Psi)$ appearing in Schrödinger's first paper well defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am currently reading [Schrödinger's papers](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Quantum_Papers/Schr_1.pdf) and happen to have some questions that maybe some expert in the field could clarify for me. Like what happens with

$$S = K \log(\Psi)$$

when $\Psi<0$. If I understood correctly, in his paper Schrödinger assumed that both $\Psi$ and $S$ were real, something that could not be true for a wave function. Thanks in advance for any help with this issue.

Note: I am aware that you can get around this issue by defining

$$S = \frac{K}{2}\:\log(\Psi^2)$$ which reduces to the original expression when $\Psi>0$ and behaves correctly when $\Psi<0$. I wonder if this may be the answer. A different possibility would be to make $S$ a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the complex logarithm, then $\log z=\log|z|+i\arg z$. (plus integer multiples of $2\pi i$ for different branches.)

Now if $z\in \mathrm{R}$ and $z<0$, then $\log z = \log(-z) + i \pi$. So the action $S$ has just changed by an additive constant. However, adding something to your action does not change the physics described by it, since the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion are the same.

Therefore I think, writing $S=K\log\psi$ is perfectly valid and as you stated yourself, you can always rewrite it as $S=\frac{K}{2}\log\psi^2$.

Comment: But what if $\psi$ is somewhere positive and somewhere negative? The added term won't then be a constant.

Comment: @Ruslan: It is not always the same: If $\psi>0$ the constant is $0$, if $\psi<0$ it is $i\pi$. Anyway, the term drops out when you vary the action.

Comment: @Clever I think that to take care of the sign one would have to introduce something like a step function  $U(\Psi)$ to distinguish both sign situations. That approach would complicate things too much.

Comment: @BruceC: Yes, but we don't care for the constant, so a step function is obsolete. We can yust take $\psi = \sqrt{\psi^2}$ and it should be fine.